# App store- releasing an approved version with an expired provisioning profile

Tags: ios, app-store

We have an update version that is approved by Apple and now ready to be released on the app store.
The version was signed with a provisioning profile that was valid when it was compiled but today it expired.
Can i safely release it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, we released that version and everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

When you release a version on the store it gets resigned with apple's cert anyways